# Показывать вложенные объекты при фильтре

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, treeview

Пытаюсь сделать фильтр древовидного списка на Vue, чтобы при поиске раскрывался полный путь от родителя до совпадения. Не получается именно раскрывать элементы.

Пример: http://120.77.84.4/

**Компонент:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Search @input="getValue" style="search"/>

        <TreeList
            class="tree"
            v-for="(branch, index) in filtredData"
            :open="branch.open"
            :content="branch"
            :key="index"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            inputValue: '',
            dataTree: [
                {
                    label: 'Lorem1',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Lorem1',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Lorem1',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Lorem1',
                    child: [
                        {
                            label: 'Lorem2',
                            child: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Lorem3',
                                    child: [
                                        {
                                            label: 'Lorem4',
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'Lorem3',
                                },
                                {
                                    label: 'Lorem3',            
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getValue(value) {
            this.inputValue = value
        },
    },
    computed: {
        filtredData() {
            let value = this.inputValue

            function f(arr) {
                return arr.filter(function(obj) {

                    function checkVal(str){
                        return !!~str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())
                    }

                    let c = obj.child ? f(obj.child) : checkVal(obj.label)

                    if (c.length === 0) {
                        return false
                    }
                    return c
                })
            }

            if (value === '') {
                return this.dataTree
            } else {
                return f(this.dataTree)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Я пробовал добавлять свойство open в объекты если у их детей уже есть свойство open со значением true

**Что-то вроде этого**

```
if (!!obj.child) {
    obj.child.forEach(el => {
        if (el.open) {
            obj.open = true
        }
    })
} else {
    obj.open = false
}
```

Но не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить на это:

`if (!!obj.child) {
    obj.open = !!obj.child.find(el => el.open)
} else {
    obj.open = false
}`

Иначе у вас получается, что условие будет выполняться всегда только для последнего элемента.

Comment: Так получается что `!!obj.child.find(el => el.open)` всегда равен false

Comment: Блин, да, поторопился )) Замените `find` на `some`

Comment: Тоже false для всего возвращает)

Comment: Мне кажется это из-за того когда вызывается рекурсивная f()